Como establecer directamente la hora para las Islas Canarias
Necesito establecer la hora para las Islas Canarias (es una hora menos que en la Península).
No sé si se puede hacer o asignar un país cercano para no tener que poner una hora menos en Canarias y que aparezca la hora directamente?
He asignado el siguiente código:
<?php
//   H 24 HORAS h 12 horas i minutos s segundos a es am o pm 
  
 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
echo "España: " . date("H:i:s");

?> 

He estado revisando la documentación y para España solo hace referencia a Madrid. https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.europe.php
¿Se podría asignar un date_default_timezone_set de un país africano que coincida exactamente con la hora de las Islas Canarias?

Podrías crear un objeto DateTime(), al que le quites una hora y después escribir la hora. Ya le has quitado una hora, por la que la hora sería la de canarias

@Maida Un problemo con tu solución es que las Canarias y Madrid cambian el horario de verano en un horario diferente entre sí.   La diferencia es de sólo 1 hora, pero esa diferencia puede ser importante incluso si ocurre sólo dos veces al año.  ¡El tiempo y las fechas son difíciles!

No necesitas la hora de ningún país africano. Puedes usar la zona horaria de londres, que también tiene el horario de verano.
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");


Debido a que las Islas Canarias están técnicamente en la zona horaria WET (que PHP solía permitir), hay otras ubicaciones además de Londres que puedes usar.

La zona horaria correspondiente a las Islas Canarias es Atlantic/Canary lo puedes encontrar en la documentación aquí https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.atlantic.php
Por lo que puedes utilizar:
date_default_timezone_set("Atlantic/Canary");


Gracias, modificare la zona horaria que  me indico Suso
